# JPA Mapping Multi-Rows with ElementCollection

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I'm trying to follow the [JPA tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection) and using `ElementCollection` to record employee phone numbers:

```
PHONE (table)
OWNER_ID    TYPE      NUMBER
  1         home      792-0001
  1         work      494-1234
  2         work      892-0005
```

### Short version

What I need is a class like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Phones")
public class PhoneId {
  @Id
  @Column(name="owner_id")
  long owner_id;

  @Embedded
  List<Phone> phones;
}
```

that stores each person's phone numbers in a collection.

### Long version

I follow the tutorial code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Phones")
public class PhoneId {
  @Id
  @Column(name="owner_id")
  long owner_id;

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(
    name="Phones",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="owner_id")
  )
  List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<Phone>();
}

@Embeddable
class Phone {
  @Column(name="type")
  String type = "";
  @Column(name="number")
  String number = "";

  public Phone () {}
  public Phone (String type, String number)
    { this.type = type; this.number = number; }
}
```

with a slight difference that I only keep one table. I tried to use the following code to add records to this table:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  EntityManagerFactory entityFactory =
     Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Tutorial");
  EntityManager entityManager = entityFactory.createEntityManager();

  // Create new entity
  entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
  Phone ph = new Phone("home", "001-010-0100");
  PhoneId phid = new PhoneId();
  phid.phones.add(ph);
  entityManager.persist(phid);
  entityManager.getTransaction().commit();

  entityManager.close();
}
```

but it keeps throwing exceptions

> Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null
>   value in column "type" violates not-null constraint   Detail: Failing
>   row contains (0, null, null). Error Code: 0 Call: INSERT INTO Phones
>   (owner_id) VALUES (?)     bind => [1 parameter bound] Query:
>   InsertObjectQuery(tutorial.Phone1@162e295)

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, i think the slight difference that you only keep one table is the problem here.

Look at the declaration of the `PhoneId` class (which i would suggest is better called `PhoneOwner` or something like that):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Phones")
public class PhoneId {
```

When you declare that a class is an entity mapped to a certain table, you are making a set of assertions, of which two are particularly important here. Firstly, that there is one row in the table for each instance of the entity, and vice versa. Secondly, that there is one column in the table for each scalar field of the entity, and vice versa. Both of these are at the heart of the idea of object-relational mapping.

However, in your schema, neither of these assertions hold. In the data you gave:

```
OWNER_ID    TYPE      NUMBER
  1         home      792-0001
  1         work      494-1234
  2         work      892-0005
```

There are two rows corresponding to the entity with `owner_id` 1, violating the first assertion. There are columns `TYPE` and `NUMBER` which are not mapped to fields in the entity, violating the second assertion.

(To be clear, there is nothing wrong with your declaration of the `Phone` class or the `phones` field - just the `PhoneId` entity)

As a result, when your JPA provider tries to insert an instance of `PhoneId` into the database, it runs into trouble. Because there are no mappings for the `TYPE` and `NUMBER` columns in `PhoneId`, when it generates the SQL for the insert, it does not include values for them. This is why you get the error you see - the provider writes `INSERT INTO Phones (owner_id) VALUES (?)`, which PostgreSQL treats as `INSERT INTO Phones (owner_id, type, number) VALUES (?, null, null)`, which is rejected.

Even if you did manage to insert a row into this table, you would then run into trouble on retrieving an object from it. Say you asked for the instance of `PhoneId` with `owner_id` 1. The provider would write SQL amounting to `select * from Phones where owner_id = 1`, and it would expect that to find exactly one row, which it can map to an object. But it will find two rows!

The solution, i'm afraid, is to use two tables, one for `PhoneId`, and one for `Phone`. The table for `PhoneId` will be trivially simple, but it is necessary for the correct operation of the JPA machinery.

Assuming you rename `PhoneId` to `PhoneOwner`, the tables need to look like:

```
create table PhoneOwner (
    owner_id integer primary key
)

create table Phone (
    owner_id integer not null references PhoneOwner,
    type varchar(255) not null,
    number varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (owner_id, number)
)
```

(I've made `(owner_id, number)` the primary key for `Phone`, on the assumption that one owner might have more than one number of a given type, but will never have one number recorded under two types. You might prefer `(owner_id, type)` if that better reflects your domain.)

The entities are then:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PhoneOwner")
public class PhoneOwner {
    @Id
    @Column(name="owner_id")
    long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "Phone", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "owner_id"))
    List<Phone> phones = new ArrayList<Phone>();
}

@Embeddable
class Phone {
    @Column(name="type", nullable = false)
    String type;
    @Column(name="number", nullable = false)
    String number;
}
```

Now, if you really don't want to introduce a table for the `PhoneOwner`, then you might be able to get out of it using a view. Like this:

```
create view PhoneOwner as select distinct owner_id from Phone;
```

As far as the JPA provider can tell, this is a table, and it will support the queries it needs to do to read data.

However, it won't support inserts. If you ever needed to add a phone for an owner who is not currently in the database, you would need to go round the back and insert a row directly into `Phone`. Not very nice.

Comment: Thanks Tom, your explanations are of great help! I was hoping that `@Embeddable` could prevent classes from being interpreted as tables. Could we make `PhoneOwner` `@Embeddable`, `Phone` `@Entity`, and the `List` `@Transient`? I just saw this suggestion on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318387/mapping-single-table-to-embeddable-collection-in-jpa.

Comment: There is some ingenious thinking in the answers to that question! I am skeptical that bvanvelsen's answer will actually work. I think every instance of the entity will get a separate instance of the embeddable, which will render the transient collection rather pointless, as each instance of the embeddable will have a collection containing one instance of the entity.

Comment: The simplest thing might be just to map all three columns to a `Phone` entity, and then group them by owner, creating some purely in-memory `PhoneOwner` objects, after loading them.

Comment: I tried their proposed solution and cannot get it work when an owner has multiple phones. I think I need to introduce this artificial id table, but does it hurt performance?

Comment: Tom, if I want to use inheritance based on the `type`, does your solution still work? My real problem is actually more complicated than this and I'm currently using inheritance, but from the JPA wikibook inheritance is not supported for embeddables.

Comment: AFAIK, inheritance is indeed not supported for embeddables.

Comment: As for performance, i think it's likely that the ORM and database will end up doing more work with a two-table solution than a one-table solution. An ORM could generate code to load a bunch of phones and their owners with a join, and a really smart query planner could work out that it didn't actually need to scan the owner table to execute that join (because the foreign key constraint lets it infer the content of that table). But a quick test with PostgreSQL suggests that it isn't that smart.

Comment: If you want inheritance, you will need to make `Phone` an entity. You can then either have `PhoneOwner` be an entity with a separate table, and a `@OneToMany` relationship to `Phone`, or have it be a non-persistent object, and do the grouping in code.